# SQLAlchemy association confusion

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a student database in SQLAlchemy with the following tables.

```
class Marks(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = 'marks'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    mark = Column(Integer, nullable=False, unique=False)
    subject_fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('subjects.id'))
    subject = relationship('Subjects', foreign_keys=[locale_fk],uselist=False,
                          backref='marks', innerjoin=False, post_update=False)


class Subjects(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = 'subjects'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    subject = Column(String(10, convert_unicode=True), nullable=False, unique=True)


class StudentIds(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = 'student_ids'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    student_id = Column(String(50, convert_unicode=True), nullable=False,unique=False)


    junctionid = relationship("Junction", cascade='save-update',
                                     backref='student_ids', lazy='select', post_update=True)
    mk=relationship("Marks",secondary=lambda:junction_table)
    marks = association_proxy('mk', 'mark')


class Junction(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = "junction_table"

    student_id_fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('student_ids.id'), primary_key=True)
    mark_fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('marks.id'), primary_key=True)
    mark = relationship('Marks', cascade='save-update', backref='mark_id_mapper', innerjoin=True)
```

I have data populated in Student Ids, Marks and Subjects table.. Now, I need to populate the junction table with the **student_id** and the **mark** foreign keys(Marks obtained in each subject are inserted in the marks table).. How do I get this done, I mean I can create an association proxy inside Student id table that maps with the Mark table and populate it there?

I went through this documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html  and I kind of understand that i need this proxy between student_id and marks..so that I can query student_id.mark to obtain marks. But how do i get that in my Junction table?

Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest it is one to many relationship (one student - many marks, http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many). So you might want to add student_id to your Marks model and relationship with Marks to StudentIds model instead of creating Junction model.

```
class StudentIds(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = 'student_ids'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    student_id = Column(String(50, convert_unicode=True), nullable=False,unique=False)


    junctionid = relationship("Junction", cascade='save-update',
                                 backref='student_ids', lazy='select', post_update=True)
    marks = relationship("Marks", backref="student")


class Marks(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = 'marks'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    mark = Column(Integer, nullable=False, unique=False)
    subject_fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('subjects.id'))
    subject = relationship('Subjects', foreign_keys=[subject_fk],uselist=False,
                      backref='marks', innerjoin=False, post_update=False)
    student_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('student_ids.id'))
    student = relationship('StudentIds', foreign_keys=[student_id])


class Subjects(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = 'subjects'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    subject = Column(String(10, convert_unicode=True), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

If you want to create many to many relationship, then you might want to look into creating association table (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many)

```
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('students_id', Integer, ForeignKey('student_ids.id')),
    Column('marks_id', Integer, ForeignKey('marks.id'))
)


class Marks(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = 'marks'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    mark = Column(Integer, nullable=False, unique=False)
    subject_fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('subjects.id'))
    subject = relationship('Subjects', foreign_keys=[subject_fk],uselist=False, backref='marks', innerjoin=False, post_update=False)


class Subjects(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = 'subjects'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    subject = Column(String(10, convert_unicode=True), nullable=False, unique=True)


class StudentIds(Base):
   __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
   __tablename__ = 'student_ids'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
   student_id = Column(String(50, convert_unicode=True), nullable=False,unique=False)


   junctionid = relationship("Junction", cascade='save-update',
                                 backref='student_ids', lazy='select', post_update=True)
   marks = relationship("Marks", secondary=association_table)
```

Anyways you don't need Junction model for creating relation between students and their marks.

Comment: But the junction table is where i will be putting together all the information. Say, student id,mark id, subject id and all the foreign keys in one place.. After these three tables are full with the relevant information, How do I get them into my existing junction table? the above design you suggest is excellent but is there a way to make use of the existing junction table to populate foreign key information?

Comment: because i may also have a new model coming up for 'student class'. Every class will have a list of student_ids, with a list of marks of students with respect to each subject. In this case, It would be better if I had a junction table with a composite key of Student_id and class, followed by foreign keys of subject and class. insertions can then be independent and the junction Model should be holding consolidated information. I'm supposed to be querying only the junction table in the end. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you are planning to have a StudentClass model it will be many to many relationship with StudentIds, so you can use approach I suggested above (association table). Then you can just add StudentClass.id to Mark model. So you will be able to get a list of marks for particular student or class or both. Again I wouldn't suggest using that Junction model.

Comment: Alright. Theres one more clarification. Suppose i need a status information in some column called "verified" for every student id, mark, and class. this verified column can be placed in the junction table. So If i want to know the status information of any of the above fields(sid,marks,class) I can query the Junction model. can you suggest any workarounds for this? Also, my students class model can be linked to my "marks" for getting the consolidated marks every class has obtained.

Comment: If I got you right each Mark for each Subject and Student and StudentClass may be verified or not. Then "verified" is Mark's property and you need to just add one more Boolean column "verified". When you need to get a list of Marks for a Student you just query Mark model by StudentIds.id. If need to get Marks for a particular class for a particular Student you just query Mark model by StudentIds.id and StudentClass.id.

Comment: Yes it all boils down to the status of a mark.considering your approach I need to have a field in a mark table but I should create relationship between Mark and everything else. Lets come to insertion. I have subjects and marks information in my Marks model. I need to tell how a student is related to his mark. if a new class comes in, it becomes studentsxmarksxclass no.of entries, which breaks the simplicity of the marks table.Which is why I thought we can have a table which has ONLY the foreign key fields and the status fields so Cleaning up/ inserting becomes an easy chore.

Comment: I guess our marks table becomes a variant of our junction model.. Which has subject,status,mark information all in one place. How do I insert now? I will put student_ids and there's a bunch of mark per subject information in my Mark class. Do i need to append anything "student-id.marks.append()" to insert the mark of every student? I have a csv file with student id and marks obtained in every subject.. fields: studentid,mark1,mark2,mark3... Now, I how do I say x studentid has obtained x mark? And,,, what do I do with the association table? :( I am really confused now. Please clarify

Comment: If you use the first approach suggested in my answer, you wouldn't need to create association table for each relationship. You just add relationship with StudentIds, StudentClass and Subject to the Mark model. Like this: student_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('student_ids.id'))
    student = relationship('StudentIds', foreign_keys=[student_id])

Comment: Sorry forgot to accept while +1'ing yor answer. You sure helped a lot..One lil doubt. how do I get the student_id information into my  mark table?? Meaning, when/how do I insert student.id foreign key info into it? I know while inserting into student_id table what marks the student has got (thro the csv file). At that time? Do you have a way to insert these using my Junction model(in my initializedb)?

Comment: Exactly! You create Student object at first. Then you create Mark object with that Student.